# How to drag folders from Finder into Final Cut without mouse [automator/applescript]

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, final-cut-pro

Hello guys I'm trying to create a Service to do some repetitive tasks that I have to perform every day. Most of the things I figured out how to automate, but there is one move that seems to be impossible: dragging two folders into a Final Cut Pro 7 project.

[image: Drag folders from Finder without mouse]

I tried using Applescript to tell Final Cut the menu commands File/Import/Folder... But apparently the program is not scriptable. Furthermore the parent folder always change, so I can't hardcode the location, although I can tell the current path to the script using automator.

I can't upgrade to Final Cut X for professional reasons, so that's not an option.

Any insight would be appreciated, even to say "You can't do that".

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try keyboard shortcuts through which you can drag folders from Finder into Final Cut without mouse    https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12724?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: The problem is I have to navigate to the right folder (that changes every time), which is not possible without some sort of scripting. I am hoping there is some sort of system event or shell code.

Answer (score -1):

I made a simple workaround using an Applescript block, asking for a user confirmation after manual dragging the folders. Its not the best solution but I can get the workflow to keep going after this step.

Comment: If you are going to down vote my answer at least provide another idea. As far as we know the solution is "impossible" for now.